# Facebook authorize dialog get "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error"

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, authorize

I develop login button on my website www.webdoanhnghiep.biz
Recently, this error happen.

Step 1:

```
window.onload = function(){
FB.init({appId:262362650517650, cookie:true, status:true, xfbml:true });
};
```

Step 2. View console:

NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?api_key=262362650517650&app_id=262362650517650&channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D5%23cb%3Df27ebe2c9c5e1ee%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.webdoanhnghiep.biz%252Ff15b114a85641a%26domain%3Dwww.webdoanhnghiep.biz%26relation%3Dparent.parent&client_id=262362650517650&display=none&domain=www.webdoanhnghiep.biz&locale=en_US&origin=1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D5%23cb%3Df25fe006513304%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.webdoanhnghiep.biz%252Ff15b114a85641a%26domain%3Dwww.webdoanhnghiep.biz%26relation%3Dparent%26frame%3Df214b3110825766&response_type=token%2Csigned_request%2Ccode&sdk=joey

Follow above link, I receive message: "Please try again later".

Anyone have experience with this errors? please help;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a stale version of the JS SDK, which is now referencing old, invalid resources.

Please always the live versions from connect.facebook.net, as this is the only way you are ensured getting the benefits of bugfixes, and not getting bitten by changes like this.

Additionally, you are both loading a copy of all.js from your own server, **as well** as loading the one from connect.facebook.net, this negates any improvement you *might* have seen from serving the resource locally.

Comment: Thank Sean Kinsey, you are my life saver :)